# The succersor operation is a injective function in the class of all the sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

**Definition**

If $x$ is a set then the successor $S(x)$ of $x$ is the set $x\cup\{x\}$.

**Statement**

If $x$ and $y$ are sets then $S(x)=S(y)$ if and only if $x=y$.

Cleraly if $x=y$ then $S(x)=S(y)$ but unfortunately I can't prove the other implication. So could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $x\ne y$ but $S(x)=S(y)$. As $x\in S(y)$, but $x\ne y$ then $x\in y$.
Likewise $y\in x$, but $x\in y\in x$ contradicts the Axiom of Foundation.

Comment: Note that the axiom of foundation is necessary: if $x$ and $y$ satisfies $x=\{y\}$, $y=\{x\}$ and $x\neq y$, then $S(x)=x\cup y=S(y)$. The existence of such $x$ and $y$ is a consequence of Aczel's anti-foundation axiom.

Comment: @HanulJeon Sorry, I'm confused. The Angina's proff is valind for the case where $x=\{y\}$ and $y=\{x\}$ and $x\neq y$ too, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro My example satisfies $x\in y\in x$, which is impossible under the axiom of foundation.

Comment: @HanulJeon Could you explain? I don't see this. Excuse me: forgive my confusion.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro $x\in\{x\}=y$. Could you see why $y\in x$ holds? Moreover, it is known that the axiom of foundation prohibits an $\in$-decreasing sequence $x_0\ni x_1\ni x_2\ni\cdots$. We can see that $x\ni y\ni x \ni y\ni \cdots $ is an $\in$-decreasing sequence.

Comment: @HanulJeon Okay, so it is impossible that $x=\{y\}$ and $y=\{x\}$ and $x\neq y$, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Right, and my first comment said it *can be possible* without the axiom of foundation.

Comment: Okay, thanks too much for your assistance!

Comment: (Correction: My previous comment has a typo. My first comment said that the proof is **NOT** possible without the axiom of foundation.)